# Google Chrome (108.0.5359.124-1) not launching correctly on Ubuntu 22.10 (X11, NVIDIA GPU)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, google-chrome, chromium

I have said version of Google Chrome installed, and it has stopped working on my ThinkPad P14s, which is running latest Ubuntu 22.10.

I have multiple modifications on the OS:

- I am defaulting on X11, instead of Wayland, since I need the ability to screen share on Teams.
- I had multiple "experimental flags" enabled on Chrome. (Such as using Vulkan as engine.)
- My system has NVIDIA Quadro T500 Mobile GPU, and I have following driver installed.

[Image of "Additional Drivers" View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqqp6.png)

What happens?

The window opens, and process starts - but the GUI completely glitches out:

[Image of what happens to Google Chrome, when launched.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVnqI.png)

- I've deleted the config file, as far as I know it resets Chrome plus the flags.
- I've updated the NVIDIA driver from 515 -> 525, Chrome worked for a while, but then continued to glitch out.
- Rebooted the system.
- Downgraded a version to 107, Google Chrome worked once, but after started glitching out.

I would just agree, that it's because of these drivers and some regression they cause with latest Chrome, but because Chromium works fine on version: 108.0.5359.124 (Chromium defaults on Snap, so theres this difference)

I thought, it would be benefiticial to ask, if theres anything I can try here?

EDIT: Tested, that the Microsoft Edge (108.0.1462.76) also works fine, and that is using the same engine, plus is installed as a .deb package. So this issue solely manifests with Chrome. What's the difference here?

Comment: `apt PURGE chrome` (i.e. remove also all config files) then reinstall -> any difference?

Comment: It launches and works "once" and after second try, it gives the same graphics glitch and wont co-operate. :/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with NVIDIA driver, after removing the drivers its working again.

So theres a regression with a latest Chrome and NVIDIA Drivers for Quadro T500 Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same problem with ThinkPad P14s, 22.04. the same version as yours, nvidia-driver-525-open, latest google-chrome(Version 108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) (64-bit)
).

My workaround is switch to xserver-xorg-video-nouveau driver, and chrome could start immediately.

Comment: Yeah the driver and Chrome are not playing out nicely, weirdest thing is that Chromium and Edge is working with same engine, with the NVIDIA driver.

Comment: looks like it still not be fixed with latest google chrome.  Very dispointed.